# Urllib raises urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: chrome>

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, python-webbrowser

I am trying to get the URL from `chrome://downloads` using `urllib` and Chrome as a user agent.

**Check this:**

[image: screenshot]

**My Code:**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
a_url = "chrome://downloads"
urlopen(Request(a_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'}))
```

**Python urllib throws this error:**

```
raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type) urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: chrome>
```

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: `chrome://` is a prefix used only within the Google Chrome web browser, which handles it as a special case. It has no inherent meaning outside of that context - IE, Firefox, Edge, Safari, Opera, etc. wouldn't know what to do with it. It's also not an actual web address, so `urllib` can't do anything with it either.

Comment: anyway i  can get the url from inside chrome://downloads via python script as i showed in screenshot ? .. i am a beginner in python and django framework, please advise

Comment: should i register the protocol "chrome://" like navigator.registerProtocolHandler does ? how could i accomplish this in python ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you're trying to get all downloaded files from Chrome, you won't need Urllib for that

Comment: i am trying to get the url of the downloaded files as in the image ? you see the image url in there from imgur ?